# SQL how can i get previous minute?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a data table whose structure looks like this.

`date  time  order_id  action   quantity`

How can I query to know how many entries are made to this table previous minute?

Say suppose the time now is 14:46 I want to know how many row entries were made to this table at 14:45. how can I do that?

The problem I am facing now is that I don't know how can I get last minute's time stamp. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` is giving me correct current time. But I tried `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()-1` which gives some decimal number.

Comment: Do you have one date column and one time column? Will be tricky at midnight...

Comment: It is better to combine `date` and `time` in one column. Now it is unnecessary complex.

Comment: jarlh I will be running my programm which does this from 09:30 to 16:15.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), specifying a date and an INTERVAL as documented for [DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add). Example:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use my query to find the last minute :

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
```